# Laravel for loop an indexed array from a single column in my database inside a forelse in blade template

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I had an for loop inside that will display an indexed array from the results column that saves an array in a DB, inside a forelse loop.

This is how I store the array

```
$final_result = ResultRecordFile::create([
            'request_id' => $request->id,
            'date_released' => $date,
            'lab_access_code' => $input['lab_access_code'],
            'remarks' => $input['remarks'],
            'results' => json_encode($input['results']) // Stores array in the column
        ]);
```

Now I will retrieve all these data in my view using blade.

The array from the db is exactly like this when I use **json_decode** for the results field

```
[
     "Result1",
     "Result2",
   ]
```

This is what I have done so far.

```
@forelse ($result->request->methodology->submethods as $submethod)
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <b>{{ $submethod->name }}</b> result is
                  @foreach(json_decode($result->results) as $value)
                    {{ $value }}
                   @endforeach
                </li>
              </ul>
            @empty
              <p>This request has no submethods</p>
            @endforelse
```

But it returns me an output of this in the view.

```
Test result for this sub method result is Result1 Result2
Test result for this sub method result is Result1 Result2
```

I have also tried this code below:

```
@forelse ($result->request->methodology->submethods as $submethod)
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <b>{{ $submethod->name }}</b> result is
                    @for($i=0; $i < count($result->results); $i++)
                      {{ $result->results[$i]}}
                    @endfor
                </li>
              </ul>
            @empty
              <p>This request has no submethods</p>
            @endforelse
```

But now it returns me this in my view

```
Test result for this sub method result is [
Test result for this sub method result is [
```

The output is supposed to be like these:

```
Test result for this sub method result is Result1
Test result for this sub method result is Result2
```

The problem here is that it returns me the whole value of the array that it should return each value of the array stored in the database.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you

```
$result_datas = json_decode($result->results);
$index = 0; 
@forelse ($result->request->methodology->submethods as $submethod)
  <ul>
        <li>
            <b>{{ $submethod->name }}</b> result is
                @if(isset($result_datas[$index]))
                   {{ $result_datas[$index] }}
                @endif
                <?php $index++;?>
        </li>
  </ul>
@empty
  <p>This request has no submethods</p>
@endforelse
```

Comment: Thankyou! That worked! Thanks for the time. Appreciate it

Comment: glad it works although didn't tested it and thank you too :)

Comment: @Sohel0415 just a suggestion, adding `isset` to `{{ $result_datas[$index] }}` will avoid any crashes :)

Comment: @JayzdeVera Maybe the `ul` inside the `forelse` should be outside `forelse`, only `li` should be added inside the loop to have one list

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@forelse ($result->request->methodology->submethods as $submethod)
    <ul>
        @foreach(json_decode($result->results) as $value)
            <li>
                <b>{{ $submethod->name }}</b> result is
                    {{ $value }}
            </li>
         @endforeach
    </ul>
@empty
    <p>This request has no submethods</p>
@endforelse
```

Comment: Now it duplicates the submethod name or it is being looped twice but the value of the results is being looped or iterate nicely.

This is the example or output:

`Test result for this sub method1 result is Result1
Test result for this sub method1 result is Result2

Test result for this sub method2 result is Result1
Test result for this sub method2 result is Result2`

Comment: can you share how you are retrieving data for `$result->request->methodology->submethods`  @JayzdeVera

Comment: this is the data:

`App\Models\SubMethodologies {#1297
         id: 3,
         name: "Unit Test",
         created_at: "2018-04-04 16:42:08",
         updated_at: "2018-04-04 16:42:08",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#1278
           methodologies_id: 1,
           sub_methodologies_id: 3,
           created_at: "2018-04-04 16:42:08",
           updated_at: "2018-04-04 16:42:08",
         },`

Comment: how do you want the data to be displayed instead of `Test result for this sub method1 result is Result1 Test result for this sub method1 result is Result2 Test result for this sub method2 result is Result1 Test result for this sub method2 result is Result2`

Comment: It supposed to be like:

`Test result for this sub method1 result is Result1
Test result for this sub method2 result is Result2`

Sorry for the bad explanation

Comment: So you just want the first result and then go to next submethod?

Comment: Now i understand, I guess Sohel's answer should work for you

Comment: Thank you for the time! You still helped me alot! Appreciated it!